# Structural description of the center $Z(R[G])$ of a group ring

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, finite-groups, group-rings

Let $G$ be a finite group and $R$ be a ring. There is a well-known description of the center of the group ring: $Z(R[G])$ is a free $Z(R)$-module, the basis consists of all $\sum_{g \in K} g$, where $K$ is a conjugacy class in $G$.

But $Z(R[G])$ is a commutative *ring*, or even better, a commutative $Z(R)$-algebra. The above description is not "compatible" with the multiplication; for example the basis is not closed under multiplication (as far as I can tell, maybe I am wrong).

**Question 1.** So what is a ring-theoretic representation of $Z(R[G])$? The best case would be something like $Z(R)[M]$ for some monoid $M$, but probably this is way too optimistic.

**Question 2.** Can we also describe the center when $G$ is not finite?

Comment: The second question is easy: the exact same argument as in the finite case works, except that for infinite conjugacy classes, there is no such element $\sum_{g\in K}g$, so you get a basis corresponding to just the finite conjugacy classes.

Comment: @EricWofsey Great!

Comment: From skimming a few search results for "center of integral group algebra", even the structure of $Z(\Bbb Z[G])$ or just the unit group $Z(\Bbb Z[G])^\times$ seems to be difficult to understand, so a simple answer to question 1 seems unlikely

Comment: @LukasHeger Can you expand on this in an answer? Also, why are units (I know that they are complicated, a lot of questions are open) related to this at all?

Comment: Maybe of interest: [Central elements of integral group rings](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF02681613.pdf?pdf=button).